# adding ng-app to drupal's body tag?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I would like to initialize an Angular application by adding ng-app="AppName" to the body element. How would I do that in a  drupal project? I've tried

```
$vars['body']['und'][0]
```

Comment: I think the cleanest way would be to create a subtheme of the theme you are using, copy the html.tpl.php in your theme and make the changes you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like the following:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
    $variables['attributes_array']['ng-app'][] = 'AppName';
}
```

Make sure to replace `mytheme` with your custom theme and clear Drupal cache.